# Facebook Как получить email аккаунта?

Tags: php, android

Пользователь просматривает мою группу на facebook. Есть ли возможность получить почту этого пользователя? P.S. Почта будет использоваться для приглашения в собственное приложение для просмотра самых вирусных новостей с разных групп.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да никак ты не узнаешь его почту! В официальном API этого нет.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61649/discussion-on-answer-by-tode-facebook---email-).

Answer (score 0):

Каким образом Вы хотите получить почту? Конечно что никак

Comment: Ну почему сразу «конечно», не всё так однозначно, тот же ВК получить почту хоть и с горем пополам, но таки позволяет

Comment: @andreymal: Даже так? Официально, через API? Или незакрытый баг?

Comment: @VladD официально, но пользователь должен явно галочку поставить, поэтому с горем пополам)

Comment: @andreymal где эта галочка? Пойду проверю.

Comment: @andreymal: Ого! Спасибо, и я пойду проверю. // Не нашёл в настройках :-\

Comment: @NickVolynkin вот тут есть право `email`, которое приложение может запросить https://vk.com/dev/permissions Только надо пользователя как-то заманить на страницу авторизации приложения, и тогда со scope=email там будет такое окошко https://i.imgur.com/2kdPZW6.png

Comment: @andreymal: Ага, вот оно как! Понял, спасибо!

Comment: @andreymal а, в приложении. Я уж подумал, что для любого сообщества.

Comment: @NickVolynkin к счастью, всё не настолько плохо) Кстати, ещё на всякий случай отмечу, что мобильник ВК не отдаёт никак (официально)